# Expanding date to include all dates in range

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset ("dl") that looks like

```
ID    start_dt    end_dt         location
1     2015-12-31  2016-01-04     dallas
2     2015-12-24  2016-01-01     kansas
3     2016-01-01  2016-01-05     kansas
1     2016-01-04  2016-01-18     dallas
5     2016-01-10  2016-01-17     dallas
6     2016-01-09  2016-01-17     houston
7     2016-01-11  2016-01-18     dallas
```

My goal is to get a dataset from this (this is a subset of 300,000+ observations) to a dataset that looks like below (what we will call "ds")

```
ID    Date          location
1     2015-12-31    dallas
1     2016-01-01    dallas
1     2016-01-02    dallas
1     2016-01-03    dallas
1     2016-01-04    dallas
2     2015-12-24    kansas
2     2015-12-25    kansas
2     2015-12-26    kansas
2     2015-12-27    kansas
2     2015-12-28    kansas
2     2015-12-29    kansas
2     2015-12-30    kansas
2     2015-12-31    kansas
2     2016-01-01    kansas
3     2016-01-01    kansas
3     2016-01-02    kansas
3     2016-01-03    kansas
3     2016-01-04    kansas
3     2016-01-05    kansas
1     2016-01-04    kansas
1     2016-01-05    kansas
1     2016-01-06    kansas
1     2016-01-07    kansas
1     2016-01-08    kansas
1     2016-01-09    kansas
1     2016-01-10    kansas
1     2016-01-11    kansas
1     2016-01-12    kansas
1     2016-01-13    kansas
1     2016-01-14    kansas
1     2016-01-15    kansas
1     2016-01-16    kansas
1     2016-01-17    kansas
1     2016-01-18    kansas
5     2016-01-10    dallas
5     2016-01-11    dallas
5     2016-01-12    dallas
5     2016-01-13    dallas
5     2016-01-14    dallas
5     2016-01-15    dallas
5     2016-01-16    dallas
5     2016-01-17    dallas
6     2016-01-09    houston
6     2016-01-10    houston
6     2016-01-11    houston
6     2016-01-12    houston
6     2016-01-13    houston
6     2016-01-14    houston
6     2016-01-15    houston
6     2016-01-16    houston
6     2016-01-17    houston
7     2016-01-11    dallas
7     2016-01-12    dallas
7     2016-01-13    dallas
7     2016-01-14    dallas
7     2016-01-15    dallas
7     2016-01-16    dallas
7     2016-01-17    dallas
7     2016-01-18    dallas
```

Eventually, my goal is to run it through the following code:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- ds %>%
      group_by(Date, location) %>%
      summarise(Counts = n())

plot(df$Date, df$Counts)
```

But I cannot get from dataset **dl** to **ds**. I have tried using

```
ds     <- dl[,.(Date = seq(start_dt, end_dt, by="1 day")), by=list(ID, location)]
```

But I get

```
Error in seq.Date(start_dt, end_dt, by = "1 day") : 
      'from' must be of length 1
```

Looking online, I have only seen examples of when either `from` and/or the `to` position are single values, but not dynamic values. Is there a package or a code that would do this expansion? Any help will be incredible!

Comment: why are you grouping by Date? Shouldn't you group by ID? Also you are looking for `difftime` function (after you convert your dates to `as.Date`) i.e. `difftime(df$end_dt - df$start_dt)`

Comment: With data.table, you could do `DT[, .(Date = seq(start_dt, end_dt, by="day")), by=ID]`. With dplyr, you'll have to make a list column and then load tidyr to use unnest... or that's what I'm told is the idiom.

Comment: @Sotos I am going to plot by date to see if there are any spikes.

Comment: You have to group by ID to enumerate the dates; later you can group by date to get counts (which maybe you know, but I think is what Sotos meant).

Comment: @Frank I see what you were saying. Then I basically have to list out all dates then unnest it to get it into a format as I would like it?

Comment: Yeah, that's my understanding. I use data.table rather than tidyr for this and so am not very familiar.

Comment: @Frank Your solution isn't working: I am getting the error `Error in seq.Date(fromdate, todate, by = "day") : 'from' must be of length 1`. I think this has to do with there not being a single date to reference `from` or `to` in the dataset. Any thoughts?